# connection to service with disabled firewall fails

Tags: networking, server, firewall

i am trying to access a service on my ubuntu server 20.04

the following command on the local machine:

```
nc -zv 127.0.0.1 9256
Connection to 127.0.0.1 9256 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

the same command from another machine in the same local network:

```
nc -zv 192.168.1.132 9256
nc: connect to 192.168.1.132 port 9256 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

- The machine is reachable via ping & ssh.
- It is a virtual machine with pass-through network adapter
- commant `sudo ufw disable` was executed
- `sudo tcpdump 'port 9256'` does capture incoming request

What else am I missing?

Update:
I found the service is listening to:

```
tcp    LISTEN 0    128    127.0.0.1:9256    0.0.0.0:*
```

I think this is the issue. Do I configure something like that in software or in ubuntu itself?

Comment: Did you try adding the port to `ufw`?

Comment: sudo ufw status
Status: inactive, and yes, i added the port even still

Comment: You need to enable it in order to work `sudo ufw enable`, if you add the port to `ufw` but disable it, it will not work.

Comment: You should modify the software parameters to listen to the real IP address. Please share the name of the software who listens, so that you may get more help on configuration

Comment: its the chia-blockchain wallet.

normally you dont want wallet ports listened publicly but this is for a test-environment (which I want to access from my local development machine)

Comment: If you want to just allow a specific ip address so the port is not publicly available you can add that to ufw. `sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.10 to any port 1337`. Make sure ufw is enabled.